# Enabling overlay-scrollbar in CefSharp

Tags: winforms, cefsharp

Any idea how to enable overlay scrollbars in CefSharp/Winforms? My goal is to hide or make narrower the vertical scrollbar for use with a touch screen.

I tried using (both stable v57 and preview v63) these command line arguments

```
cefSettings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("enable-overlay-scrollbars", "1");
cefSettings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("enable-threaded-compositing", "1");
```

when initializing but without success.

Comment: Did you ever figure out why it doesn't work?

Comment: @Alexander Nope.